in wordpress how to use classes from plugins
i have 3 party plugin for example google-calendar-events
Inside there is include_once 'includes/main.php';
add_action('init', [$this, 'init'], 5);
So I understand that this class is in globalnamespace ?
I found class in maespace \SimpleCalendar\Calendars\Default_Calendar
And in Base method
    public function get_events()
    {
        return new Events($this->events, $this->timezone);
    }
    ```

But i have no idea how can i get that data to my template file.
Any one can clear that for me or use this plugin ?


This is a bad practise. Use hooks and filters instead.
You can fetch the event list using this code.
if (function_exists('google_calendar_events_get_events')) {
   $events = google_calendar_events_get_events();
   foreach ($events as $event) {
   }
}

